# Is there a way to execute each function in an if, even if one returns false?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I was wondering if there's something I could do, aside from setting each function to a variable, and then setting it in the `if` to have all the functions execututed, even if the first one returns false (or second), ending the if.

```
public function register($username, $email, $password) {

    if($this->validate_username($username) && $this->validate_email($email) && $this->validate_password($password)) {

        $this->User->register($username, $email, $this->password($password));

        return TRUE;

    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

Basically what is happening is that the first function (`$this->validate_username($username)`) is returning false, so the other functions aren't being executed. The issue is, if the other ones are false as well, they set errors for the user. I don't really want set each function to a variable though (if I have to), so I was wondering if there'd be another way to word the `if` so that whether one of the functions returned true/false, all of them would be executed.

This is nothing of great importance - it'd just be nice to know if there was a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use [bitwise AND operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) (`&`), which don't [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), instead of logical AND operators (`&&`) which do:

```
public function register($username, $email, $password) {

    if($this->validate_username($username) & $this->validate_email($email) & $this->validate_password($password)) {

        $this->User->register($username, $email, $this->password($password));

        return TRUE;

    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

There is a bit of a semantic difference behind the scenes when working with integers; however when working with booleans the only difference is that all your methods will be called regardless of the value each of them returns.

Answer (score 3):

The thing for me is, even if you could, you shouldn't, for two reasons:

1) You're making your code more complex, harder to read, harder to understand, and harder to come back to than you need to. The next person trying to work out what it does will almost certainly be you.

2) If you need them all to execute as part of your business logic then that should be clearly encapsulated somehow. For instance you could wrap all three functions in another function whose return statement is your conditional check. This will mean making another function on top of your three variables :-)

For example:

```
function nicelyEncapsulatedBusinessLogic()
{
    a = test1();
    b = test2();
    c = test3();
    d = test4();

    return a && b && c && d;
}

function test()
{
    if(nicelyEncapsulatedBusinessLogic())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, technically, your 'valid' type functions should never be performing business logic they should just be checking for validity. Otherwise you are mixing up the responsibilities of the functions. At the moment your validate_username seems to be doing more than just validating it...?

Comment: Yes, it is doing more than validating, it is also setting a warning for the template system, so that the user knows what they did wrong.  `$this->View->set_warning('error_username', 'Sorry, but that username is already taken.', 'error');` Also, thank you for tips.

Comment: Is `test()` meant to be an example of unnecessary code? A call to `test()` will always yield the same results as a call to `nicelyEncapsulatedBusinessLogic()`

Comment: Well spotted Null :-) However the test method was just there to show how Josh could perform the evaluation while ensuring that everything was executed. In reality I imagine that test would perform some action based on the outcome of the if statement. Quite right though!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a bitwise operator & instead of && (logical) - that should run all your commands and then evaluate the if(...)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - You could restructure the function to something like this though (It's a bit lengthy but gets the job done):

```
$return = true;
if( !$this->validate_username($username))
{
    $return = false;
}

if( !$this->validate_email($email))
{
    $return = false;
}

if( !$this->validate_password($password)) 
{
    $return = false;
}

if( $return)
{
    $this->User->register($username, $email, $this->password($password));
}

return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you want to avoid the short circuiting behaviour of boolean operators.

i.e., because `&&` will be false if the first expression is false, it skips the second as unnecessary.

You'll need to rewrite your function to ensure the remaining checks are called.